# Google Maps marker not displaying at all, everything else works

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days now and it's probably something stupid that I'm overlooking so I was hoping someone could help me out here.

I have added Google Maps on my website and I wanted to change the marker, however, it does not display. Everything else works just fine. Here is my code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.339052, 4.626403),
        zoom: 17,
        scrollwheel: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var image = '<?php bloginfo("template_url");?>/images/maps-icon.svg';
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.339052, 4.626403);
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
});
```

Comment: R u getting any error on console..?

Comment: The  code that's adding the marker you should put into your initialize function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any errors in developer console? Let me guess you have been getting an error "map is undefined" or something because new google.maps.Marker() is called before initialize happen.

Comment: I did have that 'map is undefined' indeed, and I was about to add it in my question as well, but when I checked it was suddenly gone so I have no idea what happened

Comment: At the moment I have this error: Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama

Comment: You may have broken something else recently. Let's revert to your first code and then move the beachMarker lines into the bottom of initialize function.

Comment: I feel really stupid that this was it, but yes. Now it displays thanks to you! The only thing that's left to do now is to change the size of the marker. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.339052, 4.626403),
        zoom: 17,
        scrollwheel: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

    var image = '<?php bloginfo("template_url");?>/images/maps-icon.svg';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.339052, 4.626403);
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```